# Binding cascading dropdown button in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am trying to populate second drop down when value from first drop down is selected.

I just want to send data as selected from the front end to back end. I was able to see second drop down populate when first drop down was selected. But when i started to bind the data using[(ngModel)]="". The second drop down is not showing up.

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  private map = new Map<string, string[]>([
    ['India', ['Delhi', 'Mumbai','Chennai']],
    ['USA', ['New York City', 'DC']],
  ])

  country: string;
  city: string;

  get countries(): string[] {
    return Array.from(this.map.keys());
  }

  get cities(): string[] | undefined {
    return this.map.get(this.country);
  }

}
```

app.component.html

```
<select id="dispositions" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" name="dispositions" [(ngModel)]="Adddata.dispositions">
    <option class="dropdown-item"  *ngFor = 'let country of countries' [value] ="country">{{ country }}</option>      
</select>
<select id="dispositionReasons" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle"  data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" name="dispositionReasons" *ngIf="dispositions" [(ngModel)]="Adddata.dispositionReasons" >
      <option class="dropdown-item" *ngFor='let city of cities' [value]="city" > {{ city }} </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Should work with the selected value, i mean... at the second loop use the selected value from the first dropdown in <option> tag.. like <option selected="Adddata.dispositions" if that is the selected country

Comment: @JoelGarciaNuño  I am able to see the second drop down but it isn't getting populated. Did as told by you <option selected="Adddata.dispositions"> then passed as *ngIf="Adddata.dispositions" .

Answer (score 0):

You do not have any AppData in AppComponent, thus AppData.dispositions will always be null. Change it like so:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  private map = new Map<string, string[]>([
    ['India', ['Delhi', 'Mumbai','Chennai']],
    ['USA', ['New York City', 'DC']],
  ])

  country: string;
  city: string;
  AppData: any = {'dispositions': []} ;

  get countries(): string[] {
    return Array.from(this.map.keys());
  }

  get cities(): string[] | undefined {
    return this.map.get(this.country);
  }

}
```

That should let you access the AppData model in the component. Have not tested it but check it out and let me know

Comment: In   "Adddata.dispositions", Adddata is an instance of an interface where disposition is an entity of type string.  < Adddata: ClassAddData = new ClassAddData(); >  . Able to bind data from first drop down but second drop isn't populating.

Comment: But you have not declared it in the app.component.ts, thus there is nowhere for your model in app.component.html to store the selected country (dispositions) so as to show cities (dispositionReasons). Import the interface then declare it to be able to use it within html via binding